# Distance between two Bloom filters

Tags: distance, bloom-filter

I want to compare two big lists of strings (possibly up to 4^31 elements).
I tried Jaccard distance and MinHash (using Perl for the moment) which give good results, but I have a memory issue. So I represented my lists as Bloom filters.

Is there any way to approximate Jaccard distance using Bloom filters as input ? Or any alternative to Bloom filters for this purpose ?